# addEventListener on click not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, popup, addeventlistener

I am trying to display a pop up when a button is clicked ; But the event listener is not working.
**Here's my JavaScript code:-**

```
var button = document.getElementById("letsfloat");
var ppt = document.getElementById("popUpMain");
console.log(button);
console.log("hi");
console.log(ppt);
button.addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log("yo");
    ppt.classList.toggle("hideme");
    ppt.classList.toggle("nowvisible");
    //ppt.style.visibility = "visible"
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("bye");
        ppt.classList.add("hideme");
        ppt.classList.remove("nowvisible");
    },40000);

});
```

**Classes hideme and nowvisible (CSS Code)**

```
.hideme{
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.nowvisible{
    float:inherit;
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
}
```

**Button:-**

```
<div class="fixed-bottom">
<button type="button" id="letsfloat" name="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg  border-0 float-right" >Why are we No.1</button>
</div>
```

**POPUP:-**

```
<div id="popUpMain" class="hideme">
      <div id="popup">
        <h1 id="newsHeading" style="text-align: center;"> Why are we Number One</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When I click on the button, nothing happens
[image]

Comment: console errors?

Comment: I ran your code. Works for me. Maybe you have some other CSS that prevents the popup from showing.

Comment: You can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/opLuz95h/

Comment: @Ifaruki No console errors

Comment: @weltschmerz if it's some other css preventing the popup, it should at least console.log when I click on the button. That's not happening either.

Comment: also, there's nothing printed on the console for  console.log(ppt). Any idea why is this so?

Comment: @AlishaMaini Good point, it should log that. Seems to me your code never even runs.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.